# Ruby Syntax Sugar on Addition Methods

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error, addition

Quick question, why this doesn't work?

```
sum = {}
e = "a"
(sum[e] ||= 0) += 1
```

I got (expecting `1`):

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting $end
(sum[e] ||= 0) += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `(sum[e] ||= 0)` the parentheses cause the expression to be evaluated. As a result, it'll evaluate to the value of `sum[e]` (e.g. 0), which you cannot do a `+=` operation on. It won't return an lvalue/reference to `sum[e]` as you might expect.

You can verify this by doing the same operation on what would be the result:

```
irb(main):001:0> 0 += 1
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting $end
```

Or even something like this:

```
irb(main):004:0> (sum[e]) += 1
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting $end
```

If for some reason you want to keep it on one line, you can do something like this:

```
sum[e] ||= 0; sum[e] += 1
```

As dbenhur mentioned, if you are going to be doing this a lot, you can also set a default value for all keys in the hash:

```
sum = Hash.new(0)
```

Sets sum to be a hash where every key is automatically set to 0 when you access it.

Comment: Cool, I see, thanks for the edit. I was going to ask you if you know a way to keep it in syntax-sugarely way

Comment: @Hartator Sure no problem, glad I could help. Feel free to mark it as correct when you get a chance.

Comment: One could also make the hash have an [initialize block](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) for undefined keys: `sum = Hash.new {|h,k| k[k] = 0}`

Comment: just done, thnks, I couldn't directly marked it at correct (I guess you have to wait 10 mins or something) I wonder if you know a more elegant to do that than `sum[e] ||= 0; sum[e] += 1` ?

Comment: @Hartator I made an addition which creates the hash such that every value is defaulted to 0, so you wouldn't have to do the `sum[e] ||= 0` part; it'd already be set to 0, as would any other key you would lookup initially.